# How to add black bars to top and bottom for one h264 video with FFmpeg without re-encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to add a 22 pixel horizontal black bar to the top and bottom without re-encoding. I know it is possible to crop the black bars without re-encoding, but also to add them?

Comment: You've been lied to. You can't crop a video without re-encoding. You can't add areas to a video without re-encoding. At best you could add metadata so that some players will do the cropping or expansion on playback, but it would only work on specific players.

Comment: No-one will die if you reencode your mp4, people.